# Specifying Namespace in Html.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have the following code in my View

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("List", "Product")
</div>
```

The `ProductController` above is referring to the namespace `CoreNamespace`. I would like the above code to use another namespace `CustomNamespace` which has a Controller and Action with the same name (`ProductController` and `List` respectively). There is no Area involved.

I would like to do something like this

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("List", "Product", new { namespace = "CustomNamespace" })
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

@Html.Action("TestMethod", "OtherProject.Controllers.TestMethodController,OtherProject")